# Apps Script - compare strings in two arrays

Tags: arrays, string, loops, google-apps-script, substring

I am a stuck on this piece of code. I have an [Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DNcwmRzHLs4sx95juIdfrjFG4mcfv0J5iK3JNjyp_rI/edit#gid=1092045072) with two tabs. The first tab is new items. A new item is comprised of two pieces, a attribute code (string), and an item ID (number). In the other tab "Locations" there are a bunch of empty locations. Each location has primary attribute (string), and a set of secondary attribute codes in a longer string.

I have assigned these two ranges to two unique arrays.

```
function matchcodes() {

var locss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Locations');
var lastlocRow = locss.getLastRow();
var newitems = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('New Items');
var lastNIRow = newitems.getLastRow();
var itemcodes = newitems.getRange("A1:B" + lastNIRow).getValues();
var locations = locationssheet.getRange("A2:D" + lastlocationRow).getValues();
Logger.log(itemcodes)
Logger.log(locations)}
```

What I am attempting to do is compare `itemcodes[i][0]` to `locations[j][2]` (match item attribute with location primary attribute). If the strings match I want to copy `itemcodes[i][1]` (ItemID) and set it as the value of `locations[j][1]`. If the strings do not match check the next iteration of `locations[j][2]`.
If no matching attributes are found in `locations[j][2]`, I would like to see if it is contained as a substring in `locations[j][3]` (starting back at the top and iterating through the whole list of secondary attributes. If the substring code is contained in `loactions[j][3]` I would like take the same action in the first IF condition.

Once a new item is matched, the loop can break, and the next item can be located `itemcodes[i+1][0]`. If no match is found in the primary or secondary search, also iterate to the next new item.

Where I'm struggling is writing the condition statements to compare both strings and substrings within strings.

```
//for (var i = 0; i < itemcodes.length; i++) {
   //for (var j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) {
    //if (itemcodes[i][0] == locations[j][2]) {
      // I want set the value of locations[j][1] with itemcodes[i][1] 
    }
     // if no match is found in entire [j][2] column, search for substring in locations[j][3] column
    //if item match is found, or no match is found in all of [j][2] or [j][3] break loop and iterate to [i+1][0] and start the next loop
```

[Input (3 iterations)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoTSh.png)
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61RgJ.png)

Any help would be much appreciated. Or if you can point me to a similar thread. (I've not had any success finding a similar example) Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from `match item attribute with location primary attribute`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expected as the image?

Comment: I added the photos for sample input and output. In the first iteration (itemID 4728)  it would see the attribute "xafx" and match it with the first location it sees with a matching primary attribute ("xafx"). Same for the 2nd iteration (itemID 33692). However, the third itemID (25691) has no locations with matching primary attributes ("xaex") so in this instance it loops through the secondary column and copies the ID in the first location where the substring "xaex" is found

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. For example, when the cell "C2:D2" is seen, the values are empty and `xaex xbcex xbdex`, respectively. In this case, you want to check `xaex` of `xaex xbcex xbdex`. And, if `xaex` is not found, you want to check `xbcex`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, when no values are found from the columns "C" and "D", what result will you obtain?

Comment: It may help to provide some real world perspective. In my example the attributes (i.e. xaex) are unique codes that are short hand notation for properties of that product (refrigerated, fragile, organic). I am trying to assign products to locations, but locations are only capable of having items with specific attributes.  We want to check all the primary location attributes first (col C). This would be the "ideal" location to place this item. However if there are no locations with a matching primary attribute, I want to check col D. "xaex xbcex xbdex" is one string of 3 attribute codes.

Comment: If that code matches any of the 3 attribute codes in that string, it is ok to assign that item to that location (its not ideal, but still ok) So I want to check for a match in Col C, and if no match is found, check if code is contained as substring in Col D. If no matches are found the item cannot be assigned, and we move onto the next item

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. When I saw your sample input and output images you expect, I cannot understand the logic for putting `25691`, `4728` and `33692` to the cells "B2", "B10", "B11" of "Locations" sheet, respectively. And also, I cannot understand the logic for the empty values being put to the cells "B3:B9". Can I ask you about the detailed logic for achieving them?

Comment: 4728 (attribute code "xafx") can go in B10 because it is the first row where "xafx" is found in Col C. 33692 (also attribute "xafx") can go in B11, because it is the next empty cell with a primary code of "xafx". However, 25691 ("xaex") finds no locations with a primary code of "xaex" in Col C. So it then looks to Col D. "xaex" is a substring of " xaex xbcex xbdex"in D2 so it assigns the code 25691 to B2

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `4728 (attribute code "xafx") can go in B10 because it is the first row where "xafx" is found in Col C. 33692 (also attribute "xafx") can go in B11, because it is the next empty cell with a primary code of "xafx".`, in this case,for example, when a value of `4728` of "New Items" is used, the value cannot be used in other rows? And, I cannot stil understand the logic for between column "C" and "D" in "Locations", and the logic that the cells "B3:B9" are empty. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try:

```
function matchCodes() {

  const newItems = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`New Items`)
  const locations = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`Locations`)

  const newItemsValues = newItems.getDataRange().getValues()
  const locationsValues = locations.getDataRange().offset(1, 0).getValues()

  newItemsValues.forEach(([attribute, id]) => {

    const primaryTarget = locationsValues.findIndex(row => row[2] === attribute && row[1] === ``)
    if (primaryTarget !== -1) return locationsValues[primaryTarget][1] = id

    const secondaryTarget = locationsValues.findIndex(row => row[3].includes(attribute) && row[1] === ``)
    if (secondaryTarget !== -1) return locationsValues[secondaryTarget][1] = id

  })

  locations.getDataRange().offset(1, 0).setValues(locationsValues)

}
```

Learn More:

- [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: This worked great. Familiarizing myself with => syntax, and findindex() I should be able to keep adding conditions with && in each of the primaryTarget and scondaryTarget declarations correct? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Correct, be sure to checkout Array Methods if you haven't studied up on them. If you have any other questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, there is a lot of good stuff here. Would you be able to show the primaryTarget = locationValues.findIndex() with traditional function() syntax? Just so I can track how its working. The examples I see have different parameter declarations, so im trying to track what you're doing with the row => row[2] portion. Thanks!

Comment: A better way of phrasing my question. Using the article you provided, array.findIndex(row) => row[2] === attribute. I am confused at how the element (row) is being used to reference the location row{2].              
               findIndex((element) => { /* ... */ } )

Comment: I suppose in 'classic notation' it would be: `const primaryTarget = locationsValues.findIndex( function(row) { if (row[2] === attribute && row[1] === ``) return row } ) ` Basically it returns an index of the first row of a given array that (the row) meets some conditions (cell2 == attribute, and cell1 is empty). It there is no such row it returns '-1'

Comment: @NickEddy `row` is just a variable name to declare the items being iterated, you could name it `banana`, and because `locationValues` is an array of arrays, you can access `banana`'s 3rd item with `banana[2]`. In the documentation under "Syntax" they show 3 ways to accomplish the same thing, either A) "Arrow Function Syntax", B) "Callback Function Syntax", or C) "Inline Function Syntax"; all accomplish the same thing, they're just different styles.

Comment: Additionally, extra information, we're using `findIndex()` vs `indexOf()` because `findIndex()` allows logic in it's parameters, versus `findIndex()` requires a specified value.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! Good to go from here.